# Как правильно составить SQL запрос в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, сразу скажу что хочу сделать:

В одной таблице(goods) находится столбцы name и id, притом столбец id ровняется в таблице (orders) столбцу item_id, в этой таблице еще есть price и столбец paid = (0 -не проданные, 1 - проданные) так я хочу вывести проданный товар

В итоге я хочу вывести проданный товар - общая сумма товара, например:

Капуста = 120 руб(общая сумма этого товара)

Яблоки = 24 руб (общая сумма этого товара)

и тд.

Я пытался делать таким кодом:

```
$vov = mysql_query("
SELECT goods.name, SUM(orders.price) as sum
FROM goods
INNER JOIN orders
ON goods.id = orders.item_id
WHERE orders.paid = 1
ORDER BY goods.id;
");

while ($sss = mysql_fetch_assoc($vov)) {
echo $sss['name']; 
echo " = ";
echo $sss['sum'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Но у меня выводит лишь первый товар и общую сумму всех проданных товаров, хотя нужно чтоб выводило отдельно для каждого товара, например:

Капуста = 144(общая сумма всех товаров)

---

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, заранее спасибо за помощь !

Comment: вам нужен `group by`, видимо по goods.name, хотя скорее по двум полям `goods.id, goods.name`

Comment: @Mike там ms sql server, а тут mysql

Comment: @Crantisz И в чем разница ? Ну да, квадратные скобки убрать или заменить на обратные апострофы

Comment: @Mike Ну разница в том, что есть дубликат именно для mysql=)

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, sum(price) from goods left join orders on goods.id = orders.item_id where paid = 1 group by name;
```